# What AC cable coloring schema has brown, red, and green cables?

Tags: ac, cables

I would like to replace the power cable (marked with orange circle) of an old electric radiator made in Czechoslovakia some 40 years ago.

[image]

The new cable I bought has the standard blue, brown, and yellow-green coding.

The old one had **red, brown, and green** coding. I cannot figure out which was null, and which one is phase and I cannot find this coding anywhere.

Comment: Why can't you look on the plug side? Which plug it has? Can the plug be plugged in any orientation or only in one orientation?

Comment: @Justme I foolishly discarded the old cable.

Comment: Surely you know which plug it had?

Comment: @Justme yes, it was working just fine until I decided to "fix" it.

Comment: So which plug it had? Schuko maybe?

Comment: @Justme yes, it looked like Schuko.

Comment: That looks like coloured sleeving fitted over the top of the individual wires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Finbarr was right.

The red sleeve was hiding a brown cable and the brown one was hiding a blue cable. No idea why.