# What is this electric heater thermostat component for?

Tags: components, safety, thermostat

I am trying to fix an old electric heater that does not turn on. After opening the casing, I identified the part in the picture to be probably a bimetallic thermostat. When I push the part with red arrow with my finger, it makes a clicking sound that the radiator used to make now and then.

I am just confused by the + and - symbols, since one end of this part is directly connected to either the live or neutral DC wire (I am still trying to figure out which [What AC cable coloring schema has brown, red, and green cables?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/611973/92348)) and the other one to an on/off switch box. There does not seem to be anything resembling a rectifier.

[image]

The current is not flowing through this part. I suspect that it is because the two connection points marked with white arrows are disconnected. If I rotated the stripe with one of them 15 degrees clockwise, they would touch. I would like to know what is the purpose of this part.

[image]

From a different angle I see that one of the connection points is mounted on a stripe that has a built-in tension that is pulling it away from the other connection point. However, counteracting this tension is the cylinder marked with green arrow.

I suspect that this is the source of my problem and that I should just rotate the two points until they touch, however I am not experienced with circuits and I want to understand what I am doing first.

EDIT: I rotated the two points so that they touch. The radiator is working now.

Comment: I should think the +/- applies to the screw adjustment of setpoint temperature.

Comment: Are those just bimetallic strips?

Comment: @DKNguyen I just rotated the two white arrow connectors so that they touch. Now the strip holding the lower one is completely fixed in place and has no room to bend away. The only way for it to break the circuit would be if the green arrow-marked cylinder disappeared.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this mechanism either. Not enough to figure it out from photos anyways. Would need one in front of me to fiddle with. Did you test for electrical continuity between various places? If there are other parts, it's possible that there is a fault elsewhere and not here. For example, maybe the heating coil itself is broken.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Can you see any way for the switch with white arrows to be a thermal safety cutout?

Comment: If you've found an answer yourself, please post an answer to your own question. The answers don't belong in the question - not even as edits.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think you got it! I think when the cylinder marked with green arrow melts, the stripe with one of the contacts is pulled downward and disconnects the circuit. Thank you!